# Trying to scrape the following table using scrapy in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

Here's the HTML source for the page:

```
<td><table>
      <tr>
        <td class="OfficeTitleLink"><a href="mailto:example@example.ca">John Doe </a> </td>
        <td class="OfficeContent">Example (Example)</td>
      </tr>
```

I'm trying to determine what the structure of the parser should be like and I'm thinking that I need to select the text associated with the "OfficeTitleLink"; I'm trying to pull the emails addresses and associated information. Here's what I have:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//table[table[@class="OfficeTitleLink"]/td')
    for titles in titles: 
        item = example_crawler
        item ["title"] = titles.select(".//text()").extract()
        item.append(item)
    return items
```

What am I getting wrong here?

--edit--

Well, after going back over the Xpath documentation and doing better testing in the scrapy shell, it turned out that the problem was my selector. The correct selector was:

```
'//tr/td[@class="OfficeTitleLink"]/a/@href'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name in your html table example is "OfficeTitleLink" and the name of the class listed in your code is "**Official**TitleLink" is this intentional?

The class you are targeting does not exist in the snippet of html you shared.

Comment: No, it wasn't intentional and I've corrected the mistake. I'm still throwing up an invalid path error though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="OfficeTitleLink">
   @class="OfficialTitleLink"
```

That's one thing you're getting wrong, hehe.
Not sure about anything else, though.

Comment: haha, yeah, I found it pretty quickly. It's still not the correct way to parse through that table though.

Comment: You could use [SelectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) to find a CSS or XPath selector in a visual way, perhaps.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to go back and read the documentation for Xpath a little better. The actual selector turned out to be: 

    '//tr/td[@class="OfficeTitleLink"]/a/@href'